# What is best practice for syncing package.json on host with docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a best practice question when it comes to developing a node project with Docker. I could use some clarification when it comes to modifying my `package.json`. I have this basic Dockerfile for a project I'm working on:

```
FROM node:14-alpine3.16

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /frontend-local

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install --development

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "npm",  "start" ]
```

As you can see I copy over `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and then I build the image and then eventually run the container with the command below:

`docker run --name frontend-local --rm -p 4000:4000 --mount type=bind,source=\"$(pwd)\",target=/frontend-local -it frontend-local`

The issue I'm having is that I want to run `npm install` on my host machine but I also want the container to update too with the package I installed as well. How do I do that?

On my host machine I currently have `node 18` if I run `npm install` I'm unable to run it because the application is on a much older version of node. I tried installing `node 14`, install a package, but then my container did not update with the package even though I have a bind mount.

Second, if I run `docker exec frontend-local npm install <package>` the container will update but then my host machine wont register the install with git so now I'm confused as to how developers use Docker as a dev environment. What is the best practice for this issue I think should be common? Do I really have to rebuild the image every time I `npm install` and `npm uninstall`?

Comment: I'd generally recommend deleting the `docker run -v` option you have entirely.  The image will have its own isolated self-contained copy of the application and its dependencies.  You will need to re-`docker build` the image when you've made a change, tested it in your host development environment, and want to do a final integration test or deployment.  This isn't unique to Node; this is the standard Docker model for basically all languages (and the standard model for compiled languages like Go or Rust, or for that matter your frontend's compiled `dist` directory).

Comment: Hey @DavidMaze thank you for chiming but I don't think I understand. I don't have a `-v` option in my command and while I understand the use for deployment and production I simply want to use it for a development environment and for new developers to get booted quickly. Isn't rather cumbersome to have to rebuild the image every single time a `npm install` takes place? Isn't there a way to to run npm install on the host and then have the container update the same way how a code change on the host updates and refreshes node in the container?

Comment: The `docker run --mount` short form is `-v`, which is what I was referring to.  It's usually a single command to just install Node, maybe two or three if you want to use a version manager like `n` or `nvm`; that's always seemed easier than trying to adapt Docker to the task.

Comment: Thank you for your input David but perhaps I didn't explain correctly, if I take out the the `-v` or `--mount` option than my host directory will not link with the containers directory, this will take away my ability to refresh the code during development. Again maybe I didn't explain it so well but all I want is to develop my node application in docker as a dev environment and be able to run `npm install` for my `package.json` when I add and remove packages. I do not want to have to rebuild the image and create a new container every time I want to add a react library for example.